# im getting Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0'

Tags: node.js

const { app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
require('request').defaults({ rejectUnauthorized: false })

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'dev'

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? true : false
const isWin = process.platform === 'win32' ?  true : false

let mainWindow

function createMainWindow () {
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
title: 'ImageShrink',
width: 500,
height: 600,
icon: `${__dirname}/assets/icons//bayak.png`,
resizable: isDev ? true : false,
})

```
mainWindow.loadFile('./app/index.html/')
```

}

app.on('ready', createMainWindow)

Comment: Im getting this while downloading (npm i -D nodemon)

Comment: Please format your code